# How can I close the udp connection properly without throwing the "Unable to access disposed object" exception?

Tags: c#, udpclient

I need to close udp client connection without getting error says: "Cannot access object disposed" that is an exception.

This is
RehearsalStart.cs

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   using System.Net.Sockets;
   using System.Net;
   using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
   using EntitiesLayer;
   using BusinessLogicLayer;
   using System.Data.SqlClient;


            namespace PresentationLayer
                {
                       public partial class RehearsalStart : Form 
                        {

                                  IPEndPoint Broadcast;   //IP address endpoint representing a broadcast
                                  IPEndPoint Any;         //IP address endpoint representing any address
                                  IPEndPoint PIC;         //IP address endpoint representing the PIC we are connected to
                                  IPEndPoint Origin;      // IP address endpoint representing the source of the input data
                                  bool Connected;         //Indicates if there is a connection with any PIC
                                  byte[] codQuestion = { (byte)'P', (byte)'C' };    //Array of bytes that is broadcast as a search code
                                  UdpClient SocketALL;    //PC socket in UDP

                             //Delegates used

                                  public delegate void AsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar);
                                  public delegate void AddList(string o);
                                  public string type;
                                  public string name;
                                  public string surname;


                            //Constructor

                       public RehearsalStart(string Type, string Name, string Surname)
                         {
                                 type = Type;
                                 name = Name;
                                 surname = Surname;
                                 InitializeComponent();
                                 label1.Text = type + ": " + name + " " + surname;

                            }

                       private void RehearsalStart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                          {


                                  Connected = false;

                            try
                              {

                                  SocketALL = new UdpClient();
                                  Broadcast = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 30303);
                                  Any = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 30303);
                                  SocketALL.Client.Bind(Any);
                                  SocketALL.BeginReceive(ReceiveBrodcast, SocketALL);
                                  SocketALL.Send(codQuestion, codQuestion.Length, Broadcast);

                              } catch (Exception ex){

                                      throw ex;
                                  }

                       public void ReceiveBrodcast(IAsyncResult ar)
                          {
                 
                                 string MAC = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()[0].GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                                 MAC = MAC[0].ToString() + MAC[1].ToString() + "-" + MAC[2].ToString() + MAC[3].ToString() + "-" + MAC[4].ToString() + MAC[5].ToString() + "-" + MAC[6].ToString() + MAC[7].ToString() + "-" + MAC[8].ToString() + MAC[9].ToString() + "-" + MAC[10].ToString() + MAC[11].ToString();
                                 UdpClient MyUDP = (UdpClient)ar.AsyncState;
                                 string Data = Convert(MyUDP.EndReceive(ar, ref Origin));
                                 MyUDP.BeginReceive(ReceiveBrodcast, MyUDP);
                            switch (Data)
                              {
                                case "PC":
                                  SocketALL.Send(Convert(name_textBox.Text + "\r\n" + MAC), name_textBox.Text.Length + 2 + MAC.Length, Broadcast);
                                  break;
                                default:
                                 Data = Origin.Address.ToString() + "\n" + Data.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
                                 disp_listView.Invoke(new AddList(AddDisp), Data);
                                  break;
                        }
                             }

                       public void AddDisp(string o)
                          {
                            for (int n = 0; n < disp_listView.Items.Count; n++)
                               {
                                   if (disp_listView.Items[n].SubItems[0].Text == (o.Split('\n'))[0])
                                     {
                                        return;
                                         }
                                             }
                                      disp_listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(o.Split('\n')));
                          }

                       private void Search_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                         {
                                  disp_listView.Items.Clear();
                            try
                              {

                                SocketALL.Send(codQuestion, codQuestion.Length, Broadcast);
                               }
                             catch (Exception ex)
                               {
                                 throw ex;
                                }
                                  }
                       string Convert(byte[] a)
                           {
                            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(a);
                              }

                       byte[] Convert(string a)
                           {
                            return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a);
                              }
                       private void disp_listView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                           {
                             if (!Connected && disp_listView.SelectedItems.Count != 0 && disp_listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text[0] == 'A')
                                 {
                                    button4.Enabled = false;
                                    button3.Enabled = true;
                                 }
                             else
                                  {
                                    button4.Enabled = false;
                                    button3.Enabled = false;
                                 }
                            }

                       private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                           {

                                 PIC = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(disp_listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text), 3000);
                                 button4.Enabled = true;
                                 button3.Enabled = false;
                                 Connected = true;
                                 disp_listView.Enabled = false;
                                 Main Win = new Main(type, name, surname, number, PIC);
                                 Win.ShowDialog();
                                 button4.Enabled = false;
                                 button3.Enabled = true;
                                 Connected = false;
                                 disp_listView.Enabled = true;
                                 Close();

                            }

                       private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                          {
                                 button4.Enabled = false;
                                 button3.Enabled = true;
                                 Connected = false;
                                 disp_listView.Enabled = true;
                                 System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();

                           }

               }
```

And Main.cs

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.Net.Sockets;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
  using EntitiesLayer;
  using BusinessLogicLayer;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;


            namespace PresentationLayer
                {
                    public partial class Main : Form
                        {
                                      string type;
                                      string name;
                                      string surname;
                         //Members
                                      int packs = 0;
                                      UdpClient SocketPIC;
                                      IPEndPoint Origin;

                                      public delegate void AsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar);
                                      public delegate void Values(byte[] bytes);
                         //Methods
                    public Main()
                      {
                                    
                                      InitializeComponent();
                        }

                    public Main(string Type, string Name, string Surname, int Number, IPEndPointP)
                       {
                                       type = Type;
                                       name = Name;
                                       surname = Surname;
                                       InitializeComponent();
                                       SocketPIC = new UdpClient(3000);
                                       SocketPIC.Connect(P);
                                       SocketPIC.BeginReceive(ReceiveFrame, SocketPIC);
                                       packs_timer.Enabled = true;
                         }
                    private void packs_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
                              {
                                       packs = 0;
                                       SocketPIC.Send(new byte[] { 101, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 5);
                        }

                    public void ReceiveFrame(IAsyncResult ar)
                         {
                                       UdpClient MyUDP = (UdpClient)ar.AsyncState;

                                 if (MyUDP.Client != null)
                                     {
                                       byte[] Data = MyUDP.EndReceive(ar, ref Origin);
                                       MyUDP.BeginReceive(ReceiveFrame, MyUDP);
                                       this.Invoke(new Values(AddData), Data);
                                      }
                         }

                    private void CloseFrame(IAsyncResult ar)
                        {
                                        UdpClient MyUDP = (UdpClient)ar.AsyncState;
                              try
                               {
                                  if (MyUDP.Client != null) //ERROR
                                     {
                                        MyUDP.EndReceive(ar, ref Origin); //ERROR
                                        MyUDP.Close(); //ERROR
                                      }
                                        }
                              catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    throw ex;
                                }
                              finally
                                {
                                 if (SocketPIC.Client != null)
                                   {
                                        SocketPIC.EndReceive(ar, ref Origin);
                                        SocketPIC.Close();
                                   }
                                      }
                       }

                    public void AddData(byte[] data)
                       {
                            if (data[0] == 102 && packs < 5)
                               {
                                   for (int n = 1; n < data.Length; n += 12)
                                      {
                                         MEASURE.Add_I1(data[n], data[n + 1]);
                                         MEASURE.Add_V1(data[n + 2], data[n + 3]);
                                         MEASURE.Add_I2(data[n + 4], data[n + 5]);
                                         MEASURE.Add_V2(data[n + 6], data[n + 7]);
                                         MEASURE.Add_I3(data[n + 8], data[n + 9]);
                                         MEASURE.Add_V3(data[n + 10], data[n + 11]);
                                         }
                                              packs++;
                                         }
                            else
                                {
                                       SocketPIC.Send(new byte[] { 102, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 5);
                            //ADDING DATA

                      }


                    private void button_state_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                           {
                            if (button_state.Text == "Pause")
                               {
                                   button_state.Text = "Continue";
                                   packs_timer.Enabled = false;
                               }
                            else
                              {
                                   button_state.Text = "Pause";
                                   packs_timer.Enabled = true;
                                }
                       }

                    private void file_data_U_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                      {

                         }

                         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                            {

                                    packs_timer.Enabled = false;
                                    SocketPIC.Send(new byte[] { 102, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 5);
                                    SocketPIC.BeginReceive(CloseFrame, SocketPIC); //HERE is the error
                                    RehearsalStart screen = new Rehearsal(type, name, surname);
                                    screen.Show();
                                    Close();



                                 /*
                                    packs_timer.Enabled = false;
                                    SocketPIC.Send(new byte[] { 102, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 5);
                                    SocketPIC.Close();
                                    Close();
                                       */


                            }
                     }
  }
```

How may I fix this issue? I need to close udp client connection every time I disconnect and connect when I'm navigating between RehearsalStart and Main forms.

I'm working with an electronic board in c#.

Comment: Any IDE has the ability to format code. Use it.

Comment: I'm using visual studio code but when I'm executing the code throws an exception: "cannot access object disposed"

Comment: [Format](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_formatting) code and [edit] the question.

Comment: It's done. I've formatted code as I could. And I've editted the question.